# VB.net sending emails

Tags: vb.net, email

I created a form that is recorded into a database and send via email. The form allows itself to be completed once daily and is recorded only once in the database.

I've noticed that sometimes the form arrives twice in the email inbox.

To try and stop this, I created a variable and initialized it to 0. I then allow the code to execute the send command only if the variable is 0. Once the send command executes, I set the variable to 1.

```
Session("sent") = 0
If Session("sent") = 0 Then
   smtp.Send(mail)
   Session("sent") = 1
End If
```

This does not effectively stop the email from arriving twice. The strange thing is that the double send is happening for random people. I'm wondering if the second or 2 that it takes to send the email is enough for folks to click the send button a second time causing the form to get emailed a second time. Maybe I could disable the submit button on the form once it's clicked. Does that sound like a good solution? What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the data only arrives once in the database; have a process that takes the data from the db, sends the email, and updates the db with some new value to track that the email has been sent for that data

Most db allow you to do things like this atomically; you can get your db to update the email_status from notsent to processing and return you the data to send- this cannot thus run twice. Something like perhaps:

```sql
UPDATE data 
SET email_status = 'sending'
OUTPUT inserted.subject, inserted.body
WHERE datecol = @date and email_status = 'notsent'
```

Will only run once per day.

You'll probably find it's people double clicking the submit button, starting two requests on parallel threads that complete at nearly the same time and don't see each other's data soon enough to know that the email has already been sent

Comment: Great Idea. I do query the database before recording the form to see if it exists. I can set the variable, Session("sent") = 1, if the form already exists. That way, if the form already exists, then the form data won't get sent. I will initialize the variable to 0 when the form opens.This will prevent a second request from a double click doing anything.

Comment: Just completed the form with a triple click, and received only one email and entry into the database. :-)